# How do I connect Micronaut API to my MongoDB that is running in my docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, kotlin, micronaut, mongo-shell

I am trying to connect my Micronaut API service to my MongoDB that is running on a docker container. I followed steps in this guide to create authentication for MongoDB but when creating the client in the Micronaut app, it says:

```
17:51:15.346 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.ds.events.service.EventsService - com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
```

I pulled the lates mongo image in docker and started the service and created a user like this:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "admin",  
    roles: [
       { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" },
    ]
  }
)
```

I then closed the mongo instance and signed back in with auth credentials:

```
mongo -u admin -p admin --authenticationDatabase admin
```

I was able to successfully log in and could insert data into the db just fine. But when trying to connect to it through Micronaut I would get the authentication error.

Here is a snippet of my Micronaut API app:

```
    @Value("\${MONGO_PASS}")
    var pass: String = "admin"

    @Value("\${MONGO_USER}")
    var user: String = "admin"

    @Value("\${MONGO_HOST}")
    var host: String = "localhost"

    @Value("\${MONGO_PORT}")
    var port: String = "27017"

    @Value("\${MONGO_DB_NAME}")
    var database: String = "admin"

    @Value("\${MONGO_COLLECTION}")
    var collectionName: String = "events"

    init {
        val client = KMongo.createClient(
                ServerAddress(host, port.toInt()),
                listOf(MongoCredential.createCredential(
                        user,
                        database,
                        pass.toCharArray()
                )),
                MongoClientOptions.builder().build())
        val database = client.getDatabase(database)
        collection = database.getCollection(collectionName)
    }
```

I don't have any environmental variables set so it should use the default. The following is the full log after running the service.

```
> Task :run
17:51:14.930 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 826ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
17:51:15.037 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
17:51:15.055 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.ds.events.service.EventsService - checking for events between 1573689074 and 1573692674
17:51:15.065 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5dcc96f3a49ea7512bce9dec', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:145}] to localhost:27017
17:51:15.068 [cluster-ClusterId{value='5dcc96f3a49ea7512bce9dec', description='null'}-localhost:27017] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=1864800}
17:51:15.346 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2}] to localhost:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
17:51:15.346 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.ds.events.service.EventsService - com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
17:51:15.346 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  class com.ds.events.jobs.EventsJob - No events in the time range to be sent to RabbitMQ
```

Comment: How did you start the container?  (Did you publish the MongoDB server port out to the host?)

Comment: And, is the client running in another container or directly on the host?

Comment: `docker run -d -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 --name mongodb mongo` and `docker exec -it mongodb bash` to run mongo

Comment: This client is running directly on the host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. There was other processes running on the `27017` port that was causing conflicts. Killing all processes on the port and rerunning docker and Micronaut server fixed the issue.